# How solve Google Play Store is missing warning to show google map in Flutter

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, flutter, genymotion

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 4892): Google Play Store is missing.
```

This warning is preventing google map to show in genymotion device.

and this is the output of map in android 9 in genymotion:
[image]

How can I solve this problem?
All required steps to enable google map sdk for android and ios and getting ApiKey have been done and added.
This is map screen's codes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title:Text("map") ,),
        body:Container(
          width: 400,
          height: 400,
          child:  GoogleMap(
            mapType: MapType.hybrid,
            initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
//        _controller.complete(controller);
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: use actual device or Android studio Emulators with google play services in it. Looks like this genymotion emulator doesn't have google play services installed.

Comment: Thanks for response but my real device is api 19 and this google map needs at least api 20.how can i install service?can you provide me a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the error by installing **GApps** from genymotion emulator. It's an icon on top right corner of emulator and click on it. after installing GApps restart virtual device then now it has google play services.

[image]

Comment: Any solution for device without Google Play Store?

Answer (score 33):

Google core needs google play installed on your virtual device to get ads maps and core functionality that include google play SDK.

you just need to create an emulator with google play as shown in the image below one with the google play icon.

[image]

Comment: Yes creating another emulator with play store worked for me after I saw the error message  'W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: com.example.app' requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.'

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same issue, but with Android Virtual Device (not Genymotion).

In my case, I just realized that there's AVD that comes with Google Play, and there are some that are not (you can see the Google Play icon on the 'Play Store' column for those who have Google Play).

So what I did, I just created a new AVD, with the one that has Google Play on it, and it solved the problem [image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally i resolve this issue,we don't need to install anything.
We just need to enable GPS in emulator(Top right corner).

**before enabling GPS i was getting the below error**

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 2239): com.example.weather requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
I/flutter ( 2239): Latitude: 0.0, Longitude: 0.0

**After enable the GPS it's working fine and i'm getting the location**

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 2239): com.example.weather requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
I/flutter ( 2239): Latitude: 65.9667, Longitude: -18.5333

Comment: It seems you still have `requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing` problem. Are you sure that it's working fine?